# how to make Widget attributs optiobal in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I make widget property as optional in flutter for example : 
if `widget.image` is not null user image property to set background and if it null use color property

```
container(
  BoxDecoration(

         if(widget.image){
           image: AssetImage("images/background/background1.jpg",),fit: BoxFit.cover),
         }
         else {
           color : Colors.white
         }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Container(
  decoration: widget.image!=null ? 
   BoxDecoration(
    image: AssetImage("images/background/background1.jpg",),
    fit: BoxFit.cover
   ):
   BoxDecoration(color : Colors.white)  
)
```